# How do I get integers from a tuple in Python?

Tags: python, tuples

I have a tuple with two numbers in it, I need to get both numbers. The first number is the x-coordinate, while the second is the y-coordinate. My pseudo code is my idea about how to go about it, however I'm not quite sure how to make it work.

pseudo code:

```
tuple = (46, 153)
string = str(tuple)
ss = string.search()
int1 = first_int(ss) 
int2 = first_int(ss) 
print int1
print int2
```

**int1** would return 46, while **int2** would return 153.

Comment: Please don't use `tuple` as a variable name.

Comment: It's a good idea not to use `string` as a variable name either, as it's the name of a Python module

Comment: these reserved names make me want to bring sigils back

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
int1, int2 = tuple
```

Answer (score 26):

The other way is to use array subscripts:

```
int1 = tuple[0]
int2 = tuple[1]
```

This is useful if you find you only need to access one member of the tuple at some point.

Answer (score 6):

The third way is to use the new namedtuple type:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Coordinates = namedtuple('Coordinates','x,y')
coords = Coordinates(46,153)
print coords
print 'x coordinate is:',coords.x,'y coordinate is:',coords.y
```

Answer (score 0):

a way better way is using `*`:

```
a = (1,2,3)
b = [*a]
print(b)
```

it gives you a list

Answer (score 0):

Returns a match where the string contains digits (numbers from 0-9)

```
import re
tl = [(1, 11), (5, 9) , (6,3)]

list1 = re.findall(r'\d+',str(tl))

tlstr = ''.join(list1)

num = list(set(tlstr))
print(num)
```